# Batch search and replace file path

Tags: linux, search, replace

So I've got lots of m3u playlists created on my Windows machine with file path as

```
D:\blabla
```

So first I want to replace all the '\' with '/' and then D: with /media/etcetc.
How do I do that using sed or some other tool to every playlist in folder?

Comment: I believe this is a question for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it changes the root path. Then changes the `\` to `/`.

```
sed 's/D:/\/media\/etcetc/;s/\\/\//' /path/to/file.m3u
```